# Running celery beat on windows - mission impossible ?

Tags: python, windows, celery, celerybeat

I'm stuck with running celery 3.1.17 on windows 7 (and later on 2013 server) using redis as backend.

In my `celery.py` file I defined an app with one scheudled task

```
app = Celery('myapp', 
        backend='redis://localhost', 
        broker='redis://localhost',
        include=['tasks']
  )

app.conf.update(
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = { 
        'dumdum': { 
          'task': 'tasks.dumdum', 
          'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        }
      }
)
```

The task is writing a line to a file

```
@app.task
def dumdum():
    with open('c:/src/dumdum.txt','w') as f:
        f.write('dumdum actually ran !')
```

Running the beat service from the command line

```
(venv) celery beat -A tasks
celery beat v3.1.17 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379/1
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2015-03-15 10:50:33,265: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2015-03-15 10:50:35,496: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task dumdum (tasks.dumdum)
[2015-03-15 10:50:40,513: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task dumdum (tasks.dumdum)
```

Looks promising, BUT NOTHING HAPPENS. Nothing is being writen to the file.

The [celery documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#windows) on runnig beat on windows reference [this article](https://www.calazan.com/windows-tip-run-applications-in-the-background-using-task-scheduler/) from 2011. The article explains how to run `celeryd` as a scheduler task on windows. `celeryd` has been deprecated since and the command stated in the article is no longer working (there is no `celery.bin.celeryd` module).

So, What is the solution here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an actual worker running? Celery beat doesn't execute any tasks, it only queues them when appropriate.

Comment: open a terminal and run `celery worker -A tasks -l info` which starts a worker instance and starts cosuming the tasks you have just queued.

Answer (score 3):

I used following command to run celery beat on windows:

`python manage.py celery beat`

after following these steps for installation:

[Run celery beat on windows](http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/07/04/django-on-windows-run-celery-as-a-windows-service/)

it worked for me perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Celery beat and celery worker can not run with same project, as celery v4.0 stop supporting win for celery worker and celery beat.
one thing you can do, suppose your project name is a recommendation_system and your project hierarchy is as below:

```
recommendation_system
--your_app_dir
--main.py  #or manage.py
--app.py
```

and you define scheduler(for beat) and worker fun in main.py, then you have to make a copy of this project let's say named recommendation_system_beat.
now to run workers  you need to go to inside the recommendation_system directory then run cmd as :

```
 python.exe -m celery -A main worker --pool=solo --concurrency=5 --loglevel=info -n main.%h --queues=recommendation
```

where the recommendation parameter is the queue name. set concurrency no according to your need.

this will run your workers. but beat will not run, to run beat

now got to recommendation_system_beat and run the following cmd:

```
python.exe -m celery -A main beat --loglevel=info
```

this will run all you beat (scheduler)

so ultimately you need to run worker and beat in two different repo

Answer (score 0):

Run

Server:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Celery:

```
celery -A my_new_manager worker -l info -P gevent
```

Celery beat:

```
celery -A [project-name] beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

And celery beat will work, the main question is how us, the windows users DEPLOY it. Still working for it